# Locating predecessor and successor nodes

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a method for getting the successor and predecessor nodes in a binary search tree, but I am having some problems locating the bug in my code. Say I add nodes with the following keys: `"C"`, `"B"`, and `"K"`. If I print the contents of my binary search tree, I get the following output:

```
 "C" "some data 1"
 "B" "some data 2"
 "K" "some data 3"
```

When I add `"B"` it obviously has no predecessor or successor, so I just set those to empty strings:

```
    root = root->insert(root, key, data);
    root->getNextAndPrev(root, prev, next, key);
    string p;
    string n;
    if (!prev) {
        pred = "";
    }
    else {
        pred = prev->getKey();
    }
    if (!next) {
        succ = "";
    }
    else {
        succ = next->getKey();
    }

    return new Entry(data, succ, pred);
```

When I add `"B"` I get the output that `"B"`s successor is `"C"` and the predecessor is `""` as expected. However, when I add `"K"` to the tree, I get the output that `"K"`s predecessor is `"C"` and the successor is also `"C"`. I am not sure why I am getting this error since I check to see if there is no successor (nothing coming after `"K"`) set it to an empty string.

My `Node` class handles the `insert()` and `getNextAndPrev()` methods, and here is how I've implemented them:

```
void Node::getNextAndPrev(Node* root, string key) {
 if (!root)  return;

 if (root->key == key){

    if (root->left != NULL){

        Node* tempNode = root->left;

        while (tempNode->right != NULL) {
            tempNode = tempNode->right;
        }   
        prev= tempNode;
    }

    if (root->right != NULL){

        Node* tempNode = root->right;

        while (tempNode->left != NULL) {
            tempNode = tempNode->left;
        }
        next = tempNode;
    }

}
if (root->key > key) {
    next = root;
    getNextAndPrev(root->left, key);
}
else {
    prev = root;
    getNextAndPrev(root->right, key);
}
```

}

Why is it that by adding some keys out of order causes my `getNextAndPrev` to retrieve incorrect values?

Perhaps it has something to do with how I am inserting entries in my `main`. I have a loop set up as follows:

```
string command = "";
Entry* entry = new Entry("","","");
string def = "";
while (true) {
    cout << "Enter command: ";
    getline(cin, command);
    if (parseCommand(command, "ADD") == 0) {
        string tempCmd = processCommand(command, 3);
        string key = tempCmd.substr(0, tempCmd.length() - 4);
        string data = tempCmd.substr(tempCmd.length() - 4);
        trim(key);
        trim(data);
        def = data;
        entry = dict->modify(key, data);
        cout << "added: " << key << " with definition of : " << def << " to the dictionary " << endl;
    }
```

`modify()` gets called like so inside my `Dictionary` class:

```
Entry * Dictionary::modify(string key, string data) {
  Entry * entry = new Entry("","","");
  if (root) entry = search(key);
  //inserting something into the dictionary
  if (data != "" && !this->root->doesContain(this->root, key)) {
    root = root->insert(root, key, data);
    return entry;
  }
}
```

And finally, my `search()` method that gets called inside `modify()`:

```
Entry * Dictionary::search(string key) {
      if (key == "") {
         return new Entry("", getSmallestKey(), getLargestKey());
      }

      if (!this->root->doesContain(root, key)) {
        root->getNextAndPrev(root, key);
        string prev;
        string next;
        if (root->getPrevNode() != NULL) {
          prev = root->getPrevious();
          cout << "Predecessor is " << prev << " root is: " << root->getKey() << endl;
        }
        else {
          prev = "";
          cout << "No Predecessor" << endl;
        }

        if (root->getNextNode() != NULL) {
           next = root->getNext();
           cout << "Successor is " << next << " root is: " << root->getKey() << endl;
        }
        else {
          next = "";
          cout << "No Successor" << endl;
        }
        if (next == prev) {
          if (next < key) {
            next = "";
          }
          if (prev > key) {
            prev = "";
          }
        }   
    return new Entry("", next, prev);
 }
```

To illustrate the problem in detail, here is the output from running the above:

`Enter command: ADD "FOO" "D"
lookup stuff: root:  prev:  next: // gets logged out when I insert into dictionary
added: "FOO" with a definition of: "D" to the dictionary
Enter command: ADD "BIN" "C"
No Predecessor
Successor is "FOO" root is: "FOO"
lookup stuff: root:  prev:  next: "FOO"
added: "BIN" with a definition of: "C" to the dictionary
Enter command: ADD "QUUX" "D"
Predecessor is "FOO" root is: "FOO"
Successor is "FOO" root is: "FOO"
lookup stuff: root:  prev: "FOO" next:
added: "QUUX" with a definition of: "D" to the dictionary
Enter command: ADD "BAZ" "N"
Predecessor is "FOO" root is: "FOO"
Successor is "BIN" root is: "FOO"
lookup stuff: root:  prev: "FOO" next: "BIN"
added: "BAZ" with a definition of: "N" to the dictionary`

I can't figure out why when adding `BAZ` to the dictionary, the predecessor and successor is now out of place:

`Enter command: ADD "BAZ" "N"
 Predecessor is "FOO" root is: "FOO"
 Successor is "BIN" root is: "FOO"`

Answer (score 0):

I hope your Node constructor

```
new Node(key, d)
```

sets the `left` and `right` fields to `NULL`.

By `successor` and `predecessor` I think you mean **inorder traversal successor and predecessor**. Well your code seems absolutely fine to me

The only possibility is that I think you are using **common variables prev and next** to get the predecessor and successor. So try using different variables for different nodes.

After you are done getting successor and predecssor for the node B, define new variables:

```
Node *prevK,*nextK;
```

and call the function `getNextAndPrev()` with these variables.

Comment: @SummetSingh I updated my question with some output from my `main` to further illustrate the behaviour of my program. Also, `getNextAndPrev()` just uses normal getters to get next and previous values instead of passing in references to next and previous like before.